# How do I select the best transformer/regulator strategy?

Tags: power

In my project, I wish to power a Raspberry PI 2 board and a small TV display like this one (http://www.adafruit.com/products/913). The RPi will draw around 1A-1.5A at 5VDC and the spec for this screen says 150mA at 12V to 250mA at 6V.

As I'm somewhat a beginner, I'm hoping to take a 'standard' AC/DC power supply and adjust the voltage up or down to suit my needs but I'm not sure what the best strategy is? I am trying to ensure I can use a fairly generic commodity power supply and keep the costs of components down as much as reasonably possible.

I think these are my options:

**Option 1** Use a 5v 3A DC PSU and step-up the voltage to 6v using something like an LM2621 step-up converter. These apparently are 90% efficient typically and a pretty cheap.

**Option 2** Use a higher voltage DC PSU and step-down the voltage to power the RPi. A linear regulator will be inefficient (and hot) and a switching regulator is more expensive.

My questions are two-fold:

1. I prefer option 1 because it seems cheaper and more efficient. **Are there any other fairly trivial options I have not considered or are my conclusions sound?**
2. Is there any benefit to using a higher voltage in the display?

Comment: Actually a linear regulator won't be significantly more inefficient than a switcher in your option-2 scenario. An LDO linear reg which produces 5V from a 6V supply will be 83% efficient.

Comment: When designing a switcher, make sure that you **carefully follow and understand** the layout requirements. In short, the fast switching current loops should be as short as possible, and have low inductance - thus use as wide traces/polygons as you can fit. There are ample application notes for switcher designs, they all include relevant advice.

Comment: @KubaOber Are you referring to the documentation in the datasheets for the ICs? I must admit, as a beginner I find them a little daunting but I will ensure that I fully understand them - all part of the learning process.

Comment: Yes, I refer to the datasheets. Many will have example board layouts. There are also *excellent* switcher application notes written by Jim Williams. They are IMHO a required read, whether you use LT parts or not.

Comment: Thank-you, I am going to read "Switching Regulators for Poets" and "Some Thoughts on DC/DC Converters" which look like interesting starters, thanks again for all your time Kuba :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option 1 Use a 5v 3A DC PSU and step-up the voltage to 6v using
>   something like an LM2621 step-up converter. These apparently are 90%
>   efficient typically and a pretty cheap.
>
> Option 2 Use a higher voltage DC PSU and step-down the voltage to
>   power the RPi. A linear regulator will be inefficient (and hot) and a
>   switching regulator is more expensive.

You are contradicting your requirements. Option 1 using a step-up device **IS** likely to be using a switching regulator. This contradicts option 2 that assumes a switching regulator is expensive.

It comes down to this. Using a switching regulator in either step-down (buck mode) or step-up (boost mode) will give minimal power dissipation. If cost appears to be a factor look at the cheapest (or most available) wall-wart and if it's 12 volt then use a buck (step-down) switcher. If it's 5V then step this up to somewhere between 6V and 12V using a boost switcher.

The LM2621 is fairly cheap but if you look into there range of "simple switchers" you'll find a buck regulator that matches the price at a bill of material level for sure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my contradiction, a bit more research into the regulators available has shown me that I have a lot more options than I thought so am not tied into one type of wall-wart - thanks!